# Adicionar option dentro de optgroup

Tags: javascript

Quero adicionar uma  em javascript dentro de um  criado em HTML.

```
<select name="testSelect">
 <optgroup label="opt1">
  <option value="3">Apples</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="opt2">

</optgroup>
</select>
```

Neste exemplo quero adicionar a option dentro da label opt2. Algo como isto mas dentro do optgroup.

```
$("testSelect").set("value", 1); 
$("testSelect").set("text", teste);
```

Comment: Adicionar como? Clicando um botão? Ao carregar a página? Ao carregar outro elemento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com javascript puro você pode fazer assim:

```js
addOption = function(optGroup, text, value) {
  var optGroup = document.querySelector(optGroup);
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = value;
  option.innerHTML = text;

  optGroup.appendChild(option);
}

addOption('[label="opt2"]', 'teste', 'abc');
```

```html
<select name="testSelect">
 <optgroup label="opt1">
  <option value="3">Apples</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="opt2">

</optgroup>
</select>
```

Adicione a função `addOption` ao seu javascript, ela vai receber 3 parâmetros, o primeiro é o seletor do optgroup, o segundo é o texto da opção, e o terceiro o valor:

```
addOption('[label="opt2"]', 'Pineapples', '4');
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode usar o seguinte jQuery para adicionar um novo `option`:

```
$("select[name=testSelect]").children("optgroup[label=opt2]").append("<option value=4>Bananas</option>");
```

Primeiro selecionamos o elemento do tipo `select` que tem atributo `name = testSelect`.
Depois, filtramos os filhos desse elemento selecionando somente o elemento do tipo `optgroup` que tenha o atributo `label = opt2`, e adicionamos um novo filho a esse elemento.

```js
$("select[name=testSelect]").children("optgroup[label=opt2]").append("<option value=4>Bananas</option>");
var value = 5;
$("#add").on("click", function() {     $("select[name=testSelect]").children("optgroup[label=opt2]").append("<option value=" + value + ">novoItem" + (value - 4) + "</option>"); value++; });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select name="testSelect">
        <optgroup label="opt1">
            <option value="3">Apples</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="opt2"></optgroup>
    </select>
<button id=add>Adicionar element</button>
 </body>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. E sem usar jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript é possível adicionar elementos HTML usando [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). No seu exemplo, poderia ser algo como:

```
// obtem o segundo optgroup pela label
var opt = document.querySelectorAll('[label="opt2"]')[0];
opt.innerHTML = '<option value="3">Apples</option>';
```

```js
var opt = document.querySelectorAll('[label="opt2"]')[0];
opt.innerHTML = '<option value="3">Apples</option>';
```

```html
<select name="testSelect">
 <optgroup label="opt1">
  <option value="3">Apples</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="opt2">

</optgroup>
</select>
```